# Prestashop: Hide categories without products

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know if there's a way to hide categories whose sub-categories' products are out of stock.

The file with the code to show the categories is "ps_mainmenu.tpl", whose code is attached

Thanks in advance

Ive tried with some modules like "block-categories-with-counter" but it doesn't work

```html
{assign var=_counter value=0}
{function name="menu" nodes=[] depth=0 parent=null}
    {if $nodes|count}
      <ul class="top-menu top-menu--level-{$depth}" {if $depth == 0}id="top-menu"{/if} data-depth="{$depth}">
        {foreach from=$nodes item=node}
            <li class="category-custom category-custom--level-{$depth} {$node.type}{if $node.current} current {/if}" id="{$node.page_identifier}">
            {assign var=_counter value=$_counter+1}
              <a
                class="{if $depth >= 0}dropdown-item{/if}{if $depth === 1} dropdown-submenu{/if}"
                href="{$node.url}" data-depth="{$depth}"
                {if $node.open_in_new_window} target="_blank" {/if}
              >
                {if $node.children|count}
                  {* Cannot use page identifier as we can have the same page several times *}
                  {assign var=_expand_id value=10|mt_rand:100000}
                  <span class="float-xs-right hidden-md-up">
                    <span data-target="#top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
                      <i class="material-icons add">&#xE313;</i>
                      <i class="material-icons remove">&#xE316;</i>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                {/if}
                {$node.label}
              </a>
              {if $node.children|count}
              <div {if $depth === 0} class="popover sub-menu js-sub-menu collapse"{else} class="collapse"{/if} id="top_sub_menu_{$_expand_id}">
                {menu nodes=$node.children depth=$node.depth parent=$node}
              </div>
              {/if}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
      </ul>
    {/if}
{/function}

<div class="menu js-top-menu position-static hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_top_menu">
    {menu nodes=$menu.children}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove empty category in the SQL query, so in your php wrap your code with something like that :

```
$count = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT COUNT(cp.id_category) FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product cp, '._DB_PREFIX_.'product pr WHERE cp.id_category = '.$id_current_category .' AND cp.id_product = pr.id_product AND pr.active = 1' );
if($count>0)
{
    //your actual code to get the category
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Do you know where is the file where I can set that code?